# F# equality behavior on union type with function case

Tags: f#, equality, discriminated-union

I'm trying to understand this equality behavior. The record equality test fails, but the equality test of the sole property of the records passes. Is this a bug? Or can someone explain this behavior?

```
type TestUnion =
    | Case1
    | Case2 of (int -> string)

type TestType =
    {
        Foo : TestUnion
    }

open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

[<TestClass>]
public Testing() =

    let a = { Foo = Case1 }
    let b = { Foo = Case1 }

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.ThisFails () =
        Assert.AreEqual(a, b)

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.ThisPasses () =
        Assert.AreEqual(a.Foo, b.Foo)
```

I know the reason it fails is because one of the cases is a function. If I change it to a simple value, both tests pass. But it is odd to me that a) equality fails at all because the simple case with no value is used and b) the record equality fails while the property equality passes.

*Note: The record equality will fail when other simple properties are present also. IOW, the union type poisons equality for the whole record, even though the union type property tests as equal.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Assert.AreEqual` method tries to be clever and of course fails. Given two objects, the first thing this method will do is test for reference equality: `obj.ReferenceEquals( Case1, Case1 )`. This works right away, because all `Case1` values are the same object.

Now, if the `Assert.AreEqual`'s parameters don't turn out to be the same object, it will go ahead and call `obj.Equals`. For your record, the implementation of `Equals` will always return false, because the F# compiler did not implement an equality for it. Why? Because types of some fields (namely, `TestUnion`) do not have equality. Why doesn't `TestUnion` have equality? Because it has at least one case with a type that does not have equality - namely, `int -> string`.

If you change `Case1` to something like `Case1 of int` and then try `Assert.AreEqual( Case1 42, Case1 42 )`, the test will fail. This will happen, because the two instantiations of `Case1 42` will no longer be the same object (unless you compile with optimizations), and the `Equals` implementation for `TestUnion` will always return false.

If you really want this to work (and you really know how to compare functions), you can always just implement `Equals` yourself:

```
[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]
type TestType = { Foo: TestUnion }
    with 
        override this.Equals other = (* whatever *)
        override this.GetHashCode() = (* whatever *)
```

Note that you have to do quite a dance to accomplish this: you have to add a `CustomEquality` and `NoComparison` (or `CustomComparison`) attributes, and also implement `GetHashCode`. If you don't do any of that, the compiler will complain that your implementation of equality is inconsistent.

The "correct" solution, however, is to always use F# facilities as much as possible. In this specific case, this would mean using the `=` operator for comparison:

```
Assert.IsTrue( Case1 = Case1 )
```

This way, if you're missing something, the compiler will always tell you:

```
Assert.IsTrue( a = b )
// The type 'TestType' does not support the 'equality' constraint because blah-blah-blah
```

The F# compiler is generally more correct and consistent than the underlying .NET CLR.

Comment: Great explanation. I did try `Assert.AreEqual(Case1 42, Case1 42)` and that indeed failed to my surprise. I thought I was already being clever by making my own `areEqual` function which required the same type (but still called `Assert.AreEqual`). That was still too indirect for the compiler to give an error.

Answer (score 2):

You should be seeing this error if you try to directly compare `a = b`:

> error FS0001: The type 'TestType' does not support the 'equality' constraint because it is a record, union or struct with one or more structural element types which do not support the 'equality' constraint. Either avoid the use of equality with this type, or add the 'StructuralEquality' attribute to the type to determine which field type does not support equality

Function values don't support *equality* in F#, so you can't have structural equality on a type like this. I'd suspect the `Assert.AreEqual` calls are *not* relying on F#'s structural equality comparisons.

```
let areEqual x y = obj.Equals(x, y)
> areEqual a.Foo b.Foo;;
val it : bool = true
```

Comment: Redacting previous comment. I had changed the type when I was playing with it. You are correct. When I directly do an equality comparison, I get the error.